# -devilspie doesn't play nice with spawning new terminals

Tags: bash, scripting, terminal, devilspie, lxterminal

I'm trying to configure devilspie so that on detection of opening a certain directory it runs a script to mount that directory over a network.

I don't think the script itself is too important but just in case I'll display its code here:

```
#!/bin/bash
ldir=/home/LinPC/Desktop/Pictures
rdir="//WinPC/My Pictures"

if [ !"$(ls -A $ldir)" ] ; then
    sudo mount.cifs "$rdir" "$ldir" -o user=someguy
fi
```

The script works when ran from a shell.

I configure devilspie using gdevilspie interface (which may be a part of the problem?).  I know the conditions are being met as I see a window flash briefly but the shell instantly closes.  I use the following line for the 'spawn_sync' action:

```
lxterminal -e sudo bash ~/mount_music.sh
```

Typing the above into a shell also spawns the shell and runs the script successfully (prompting me for input).  Triggered by devilspie it does not prompt me, it opens and closes before I get to see the output.

(On a side note, entering into gdevilspie spawn_sync action:

```
lxterminal -command="sudo bash ~/mount_music.sh"
```

then closing the dialog and reopening it, causes everything after the equals symbol to have been wiped out; a bug in gdevilspie?)

Comment: Looks like `gdevilspie` wraps `devilspie2` (a different application with a similar name).